# Having trouble with basic greasemonkey script - GM.getValue / GM.setValue (I think)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a basic Greasemonkey script but I'm running into some problems. Essentially, the script will refresh the page and count the number of images on a page. If the number of images increased, it will alert me and make that tab active. If the number of images are the same or less, it will continue refreshing the page at set intervals.

I think that the best course of action, based on what I've looked at, would be to use GM.getValue / GM.setValue in order to store the number of images to compare it with the new image count. I just can't seem to get it to even run though - I think my logic is sound, but it's just a syntax issue despite trying different variations. I've never used Javascript before!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        *Page Refresher
// @include     *
// ==/UserScript==
// @grant    GM.getValue
// @grant    GM.setValue

var refreshRate = 10000; //Refreshes every 10s
var newCount =document.images.length; //Counts images on page

if (GM.getValue('oldCount',-1) === -1){
  GM.setValue('oldCount',newCount);
  window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload() ;},refreshRate);
} else {
  if (newCount <= GM.getValue('oldCount')){
      GM.setValue('oldCount',newCount);
      window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload() ;},refreshRate);
} else {
     if (newCount > GM.getValue('oldCount')){
         GM.setValue('oldCount',newCount);
         alert('More images!');
      }
}
```

That's the rough code I'm working with. I'm just not really sure where I'm going wrong - I'm sure it's something pretty straightforward, but I'm definitely struggling. Thank you!

Comment: From what you describe you are doing, you should consider using `localStorage`, rather than userscript storage, as long as it doesn't conflict with anything the site is storing in `localStorage`. You will probably find it easier, and the data will stay per-site (i.e. you could run the script on more than one site without worrying about keeping the data from different sites separate in userscript storage). OTOH, if you are wanting to be able to run the script on multiple pages of the same site at the same time, you will still need a method for keeping the count separate by page URL.

Answer (score 2):

Those functions (like [GM.getValue](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.getValue)) in GM4 are asynchronous. That means the value they return is not immediately available like in synchronous API.

In asynchronous code, you need to wait for the response.

Note: You should get the value of oldCount once and cache it instead of getting over and over from stored value.
There is also an error in the Metadata Block.

Here is an example based on your code (code simplified)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Page Refresher
// @include     *
// @grant       GM.getValue
// @grant       GM.setValue
// ==/UserScript==

(async () => {

  const refreshRate = 10000;                      // Refreshes every 10s
  const newCount = document.images.length;        // Counts images on page
  const oldCount = await GM.getValue('oldCount', -1);

  await GM.setValue('oldCount', newCount);        // save new value, wait since refreshing before saving can cause issues

  if (newCount > oldCount){ 
    alert('More images!'); 
  } 
  else { 
    setTimeout(() => { location.reload(); }, refreshRate); 
  } 

})();
```